# Real-time data exchange between Python and Fortran

Tags: python, fortran

My dear friends,
many thanks for your comments, but I still need your help. For example:

**Fortran code:**

```
program simple
implicit none
integer:: a, b, c
a = 1
b = 2
c = a + b
write(*,*) 'c = ', c
end program simple
```

Now, I want to use the calculated in Fortran value "c" in Python.

**Python code:**

```
# c = received data from Fortran
a = c + 1
# the variable "a" shall be sent to Fortran
```

Now, the calculated in Python value "a" shall be sent to Fortran, to calculate the new value of "c":

**Fortran Code** (I know, that this code does not work):

```
program simple
implicit none
integer:: a, b, c, recv_data
!recv_data = the calculated value in Python "a"
a = recv_data
b = 2
c = a + b
write(*,*) 'c = ', c
end program simple
```

I do not want to use the third party file (e.g. .txt), where the values can be written and read. If I would use only Python, I would use socket function (TCP/IP for server and client) to exchange data between client and server.

Are there similar options to implement a real time data exchange between Fortran and Python?

If you could provide a small example for solving this problem, I would be appreciate.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: https://numpy.org/devdocs/f2py/python-usage.html

Comment: You have every form of inter-process communication and mixed-language programming available to you, and this is not so dependent on whether it's Fortran and Python talking, or C and Julia. To help us narrow this down for you, please provide more detail on what you know about such techniques, what particular requirements you have and what limitations may apply. (Otherwise this really is far too broad for a sensible collection of answers.)

Comment: @TomMcLean, Do I correct understand? By means of F2PY I create a third party file, where write, rewrite and read a data. So, I do not save data in buffer.

Comment: @francescalus, I am new to programmin. But, I try to describe my problem and limitations. I have an ABAQUS subrotine writen in Fortran. In this subroutine I calculate the value "a". As soon the value "a" is calculated it shall be sent to Python. This value is used to calculate the other value "b". As soon the value "b" is calculated it shall be sent back to Fortran to calculate the new value "a". I would like to avoid the communication through third party file, where I can write and read the data.  I would like to use some thing like Sockets in Python.

Comment: @YuriiYarema Your problem can be readily solved via Python `ctypes` and Fortran-C interoperability features. You do not layout your problem precisely. But [here is an example demonstration](https://www.cdslab.org/recipes/programming/fortran-dll-getpower/fortran-dll-getpower) of how it can be done.

Comment: To call python routines from Fortran, forpy may be useful https://github.com/ylikx/forpy